# How can I find an elment in the parent of element

Tags: javascript

i have the following html code:

```
<div class=imgHolder>
      <img src="some address"/>     
       <a class="del" onClick="function">delete</a>
</div>
```

how find image tag in the parent's of  by pure java script

Comment: don't call your function function...it's a keyword

Comment: I'd means some function

Comment: The easiest way is to learn about `previousSibling` and `nextSibling`, though learning about `parentNode`, and `childNodes` would also work.

Comment: What do you want to do with the `src` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class=imgHolder>
  <img src="some address"/>     
   <a href="javascript:void();" class="del" onclick="deleteThis(this);">delete</a>
</div>
```

Script:

```
function deleteThis(sender){
    var childs = sender.parentNode.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++){
        if (childs[i].tagName === 'img')
            alert(childs[i].src);
    }
}
```

OR, if you're sure `img` will be always before link.

```
function deleteThis(sender){
    if (sender.previousSibling.tagName === 'img')
       alert(sender.previousSibling.src);
}
```

Comment: `delete` is a keyword!

Comment: I would like to know why my answer is downvoted.. is it wrong anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript:**

```
function clickFunc(e){

var tgt = e.target;
var parent = tgt.parentNode;
var img = parent.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

parent.removeChild(img);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class=imgHolder>
    <img src="some address"/>     
    <a class="del" onClick="clickFunc">delete</a>
</div>
```

I tried to write it as self explanatory, but a walk through:

1. `e` is the click event.
2. `e.target` is what the user clicked on (Your anchor tag)
3. `parent` is the parent node of the anchor.
4. `img` is the first image in the parent node.
5. Remove `img` from `parent`.